# How to 'detect' a change of value in a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count, distinct

im new to SQL, i wanted to ask:

I have combined multiple tables with CTE and join and resulting on this [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTc2G.png).

From this table, I wanted to detect and count how many workers changed the category from the 1st or 2nd job.

For example, Jonathan Carey has 'Sales Lapangan' as his first job_category, and changed to 'other' on his 2nd job, i wanted to count this job_category change as one.

I tried Case when, and while but i'm getting more confused.

This is my syntax for the table i created:

```
with data_apply2 as(with data_apply as(with all_apply as(with job_id as(select job_category,
row_number() over(order by job_category) as job_id
from job_post
group by job_category)
select jp.*, job_id.job_id from job_post jp
join job_id
on job_id.job_category=jp.job_category)

select ja.worker_id, wk.name, ja.id as id_application, aa.job_category, aa.job_id
from job_post_application ja
join all_apply aa
on aa.id=ja.job_post_id
join workers wk
on wk.id = ja.worker_id
order by worker_id,ja.id)

select *, 
row_number() over(partition by worker_id order by worker_id) as worker_num 
from data_apply)
```

Thank You

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `SELECT workerid, name, MAX(id_application), COUNT(jobcategory) FROM ... HAVING COUNT(jobcategory) > 1 GROUP BY workerid, name` or such.

Comment: @forpas my expected output was like

worker_id | category change(boolean):
1234         | 1,
1456         | 0,
2567         | 0,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by worker and check the number of distinct job categories:

```
SELECT worker_id, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT job_category) > 1 category_change 
FROM data_apply
GROUP BY worker_id;
```

Comment: wow, didnt expect a simple count distinct works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

select case when job_category<> job_category then 1 else 0 end as cnt
from
(
select
worker_id,
name,
id_application,
job_category,
job_id,
worker_num,
coalesce(lag(job_category) over(partition by worker_id order by id_application), job_category) as job_category
from
sales_table
) x

This should help, using the Lag function I'm accessing the data over the previous row. and comparing it with the job_category and if they are not equal  we are counting them as 1.